# Generate list of matches starting from players list

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, distinct-values

I have the below scenario:

```
Input data: 

Table t1:
+-------------+
| Teams       |
+-------------+
| India       |
| Australia   |
| England     |
| Italy       |
+-------------+

Required output:
+-------------+------------+
| Team1       |   Team2    |
+-------------+------------+
| India       | Australia  |
| India       | England    |
| India       | Italy      |
| Australia   | England    |
| Australia   | Italy      |
| England     | Italy      |
+-------------+------------+
```

i.e. the countries (column Team1) who are playing against which country (column Team2).

I tried using full outer join but wasn't able to get distinct values. Can we achieve this through a single sql query?

Comment: If you want the output in a particular order ( say matches with India should come before Australia ), it is necessary to have an id column in your table. If that isn't your requirement, the answer provided should work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a "half" join on teams not being equal:

```
select a.team, b.team
from teams a
join teams b on a.team < b.team
```

See [live demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/763cf5/1).

The use of `a.team < b.team` rather than `a.team != b.team` returns only *combinations* rather than *permutations* - you get only one side of each join, giving you only distinct combinations.